# export pdf from phpreport in server cannot show

Tags: php, jquery, css, linux, pdf

I 'm making the web with php maker and phpreport , I try localhost all is well, but when I upload to the Internet server . I can not export pdf.

i try to see in chrome

`jquery-1.12.0.min.js:3 GET http://***.net.id/calon_pelanggansmry.php?export=pdf&custom=1&exportid=9nfsii4niaq41qhuk8u0c6fhh0_1463040227389 500 (Internal Server Error)`

could any body help, thanks

Comment: If you get a `500 (Internal Server Error)`, check your servers error log for the concrete error.

Comment: hi thanks for your information, now i have migrate from nginx to apache and everythinks is fine..